# Lg optimus L 70 system update won't work

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I had checked my system update file and there is a file with 200 mb to download. I click on it and that annoying little message comes up: Insufficient storage available to download......I have 765 mb available. I google it and it's a pretty common but solutions put on absolute garbage and the *#9900# thing won't because it only works for Samsung. Another thing, should I even update or it doesn't matter and I can leave it how it is. Please help because I can't find anyone with my phone type and in my same situation. App updates and downloads work fine, just this stupid thing. Please help, anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SD card slot . Shove a 2gb+ card in there and point it to download to the SD card. You can use chrome or some other browser that will let you change  download location for every download. Only if this does not work - you can try increasing the space in /system
/System and /mnt/sdcard1 these are different partitions.Try clearing the /system partition by moving some apps that do not appear to be needed system apps. This can be done using Link2SD app. You have to be very choosy- if you select some vital app and make it non system it can be a problem.